# Using cursor in pl/sql block print the name,salary and deptno of all employees who belongs to deptno 20

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
declare
  cursor c_emp is
    select ename,sal,deptno from emp;
  v_name emp.ename%type;
  v_sal emp.sal%type;
  v_deptno emp.deptno%type;
begin
  open c_emp;
  fetch c_emp into v_name,v_sal,v_deptno;
  dbms_output.put_line(v_name||' '||v_sal||' '||v_deptno);
end;
/
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The question is print the name,salary and deptno of all employees who belongs to deptno 20 @GurV

Comment: What is **your** question - not the assignment you've been given. You haven't said if you're having a problem, getting an error, or just not seeing any (or enough) output. [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43662747/edit) to explain what you need help with.

Comment: So you've almost answered your own question - you just need to add a loop in there.

Comment: I can't get that loop please tell me @ChristianPalmer

Comment: There are lots of examples around, [including this one in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/static.htm#BABCFDJE).

Comment: I got the answer anyways Thank You Guys

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this...?

```
declare
  cursor c_emp is
    select ename,sal,deptno from emp;
  v_name emp.ename%type;
  v_sal emp.sal%type;
  v_deptno emp.deptno%type;
begin
    open c_emp;
        loop    
            fetch c_emp into v_name, v_sal, v_deptno;
            exit when c_emp%NOTFOUND;
            dbms_output.put_line(v_name||' '||v_sal||' '||v_deptno);
        end loop;
    close c_emp;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare
  cursor c_emp is
    select ename,sal,deptno from emp where deptno=20;
  v_name emp.ename%type;
  v_sal emp.sal%type;
  v_deptno emp.deptno%type;
begin
    open c_emp;
        loop    
            fetch c_emp into v_name, v_sal, v_deptno;
            exit when c_emp%NOTFOUND;
            dbms_output.put_line(v_name||' '||v_sal||' '||v_deptno);
        end loop;
    close c_emp;
end;
/
```